# Qt5.10.1 Cross-Compiled to Raspberry Pi Zero W uses EGLFS instead of XCB

Tags: raspbian-stretch, c++, qt

I have been trying to create a GUI application using Qt5 on Raspbian Stretch, but the application doesn't launch correctly unless I specifically tell it to run as XCB. This is fine, as I don't need it running in EGLFS mode, so I went back and configured Qt5 with no EGLFS support, but it still does the same thing.

Configure:

`/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1/configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /home/bast/cross-compile-rpi/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwebengine -skip qtscript -nomake examples -make libs -no-icu -xcb -no-eglfs -nomake tests -nomake examples -v`

When I run make and make install, then rsync the files to my Pi it still defaults to EGLFS mode and the application freezes with this output:

`[9;0]Unable to query physical screen size, defaulting to 100 dpi.
To override, set QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH and QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT (in millimeters).`

Everything works perfectly if I run it as XCB, and I need the application to run along-side other windows, it isn't meant to be run as the primary window for the Pi.